# Where is externally loaded resource (JS/CSS) Cache Control TTL set?

Tags: browser-cache, cache-control

We have an SEO individual telling us to change the Cache TTL properties for a number of elements on the page - including externally loaded JS and CSS files.

Can you do that, without setting up those resources to be served from your server?  Aren't the cache TTL settings set by the server it comes from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the cache TTL is set by the resource server, so you'd have to rehost them to influence them.